# How to prevent vulnerability scanning tools from scanning my VPS?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I noticed in the logs that my server is beeing scanned continuously, I know that from apache / postfix/ dovecot logs.

Example from apache error log :

```
==> error.log <==
[Fri Mar 01 10:11:30.796076 2019] [:error] [pid 25454] [client ***MyIp***:11170] script '/var/www/html/cnm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:11:40.755692 2019] [:error] [pid 25182] [client ***MyIp***:14932] script '/var/www/html/51.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:36.128821 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/cadre.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:36.594905 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/mm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:37.082301 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/test.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:38.201763 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/1q.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:38.693411 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/1111.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:39.142149 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/errors.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:40.289652 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/q.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 01 10:14:43.169735 2019] [:error] [pid 25513] [client ***MyIp***:25016] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

In addition to the risk of being hacked, these attacks generate too much logs !

Is there a way to stop them without affecting the "real" visitors ?

Comment: I think the only way is to block their IP. Is that something you can do?

Comment: Not always the same IP. but yes this sould at least eliminate temporarely some attackers.

Comment: There are lots of ways to temporarily block "bad" IPs. Fail2ban and other tools do this for you. Many options are found in the duplicates I listed.

Comment: Ok I will check them. thanks . Indeed I have to use fail2ban as i saw SSH login attempts too.